# What is the equivalent of binary(8) and varbinary(16) of MySQL in BigQuery?

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I'm moving data from MySQL table that has columns of types :

```
binary(8) 
varbinary(16)
```

And I can't find the equivalent types in BigQuery documentation 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types

What are the equivalent types? I need to know what to choose for the creation of the table in BigQuery

Comment: Pretty sure it's BYTES datatype "The BYTES version operates on **raw bytes** rather than Unicode characters. Casts between STRING and BYTES enforce that the bytes are encoded using UTF-8."

Comment: @RaymondNijland If I choose BYTES it's unlimited? so there is no diffrance between binary(8) and varbinary(16)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BigQuery simply provides a `BYTES` type, which is of variable length. To write a bytes literal, you prefix the string with `b`, e.g.

```
SELECT b'\x10\x33';
```

You can read more in the [data types documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#bytes-type). Note that the BigQuery UI shows BYTES values in base64 format.

Comment: You need to use `BYTES`