# What is the optimal datatype of a hash string in a Google BigQuery column?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 100 billion records in a BigQuery table. There is an ID field created using a hash function with 64 characters like this: `1f5ec82dff18c01aac6f4c07feaedf5b4ad43fe8815a5da732d5fe445a788f59`. In my BQ table, the datatype of ID is `STRING`, but at this point, it seems extremely wasteful.

What should the datatype of that column be and how do I convert to it in BQ sql?

Comment: Your values are implicitly hexadecimal representations of binary values. 
As such, use BigQuery's binary type `BYTES` and you'll use half as much space as encoding as UTF-8 strings (32 bytes rather than 64 single-byte characters). 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54926399/what-is-the-equivalent-of-binary8-and-varbinary16-of-mysql-in-bigquery

Comment: @MatBailie: Thank you. How would you cast from the STRING to BYTES data types in BQ SQL? Also, would you write an answer, so I can vote you up?

Comment: The linked question's answer shows you how.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the data type to “BYTES”.

> BYTES also represent variable-length data but, as the name suggests,
> they operate on raw bytes rather than Unicode characters. For that
> reason, STRING and BYTE types cannot be used interchangeably.

```
declare variable1 BYTES(10);
set variable1=cast('HeuTnDaw=q' as BYTES);
select variable1;
```

You can see more [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#bytes_type).